# How to open "slmgr /xpr" window using python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I tried using subprocess.run with administrator privileges but keep getting error "FileNotFoundError". My task is to check the if the Windows OS is genuine. It would be great if someone could provide other way of doing this.